# Should I Use HTML5 Syntax?

Tags: xhtml, html, syntax

I was looking for a reference to make sure I was disabling an element correctly. When XHTML came out, I was always taught to disable an element like so:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
```

XHTML was all about making the HTML syntax more strict by following more rules. But, then I went to the HTML5 working draft on W3C and noticed the [following on their boolean attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute) (such as disabled):

```
<label><input type=checkbox checked name=cheese disabled> Cheese</label>
```

I mean, it looks like the upcoming HTML5 syntax will be much more loose, like the old school days before XHTML. Maybe I'm missing something though.

So, here's the question: Should I use the HTML5 syntax style (the one in the W3C working draft) for new HTML that I write on my site (I am using the HTML5 doctype)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> was all about making the HTML syntax more strict by following more rules.

Fewer rules actually. They removed exceptions. For example "Attribute values must be quoted unless the value conforms to certain conditions" became "Attribute values must be quoted".

Of course, you then add in the HTML compatibility guidelines, because XHTML never really took off and almost everyone served it as text/html resulting in "Elements that cannot have content must have the end tag omitted" becoming "Elements that cannot have content must have the end tag omitted and use self-closing tag syntax instead".

> I mean, it looks like the upcoming HTML5 syntax will be much more loose, like the old school days before XHTML.

The syntax rules basically encompass everything that was allowed in HTML and XHTML with differences between the two falling on the XHTML side. (e.g. `<foo />` means `<foo>` and not `<foo>&gt;`).

> Should I use the HTML5 syntax style (the one in the W3C working draft)

The question as to the style you use is somewhat subjective. There are merits to both the conciseness of leaving out things that are optional and the explicitness of not.

If you use HTML5 then you should write valid HTML5. The example you give is not the only acceptable approach though.

Comment: With the HTML5 doctype being used, how would you write the second example I gave (as it is valid HTML5 according to W3C)? Or would you use it as is?

Comment: You can write it that way, or you can write it XHTML style, or you can write it somewhere between the two. I'm going to leave my personal preference out of it as (as well as there being merits on both sides, as I mentioned before) it is religious territory and subject to unproductive flame wars.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the HTML5 doctype, what makes you think that you should **not** be using HTML5 syntax?  HTML5 is **not** an XML variant - it's **HTML**.

That said, personally I always quote attribute values because it seems uncouth not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post on W3C should make things clear: [HTML 5, one vocabulary, two serializations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2008/01/html5-is-html-and-xml.html).

In short, HTML5 allows you to use either the HTML syntax or the XML syntax -- both are equally valid, so the choice is yours.

Personally, I would go with the HTML syntax because it's simpler, and further, HTML is not based on XML, so I don't see any reason to use the XML syntax.

Comment: The HTML syntax is not simpler. It is full of exceptions. That said, using the XML serilization and serving as application/xhtml+xml will introduce some serious compatibility problems.