# Can I stop :hover from being applied to an element?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have some CSS...

`button:hover { font-weight: bold }`

How can I prevent the `:hover` styles from being applied, at will?  My target use case is when the element is disabled.  For example, with this HTML...

`<button disabled>Click me</button>`

...the `:hover` CSS is still applied.  The button gets faded out but the `:hover` effect can still be seen.  How can this be stopped?

Comment: With some JS you could apply the :hover element only for enabled elements by adding and removing a class. So `button:hover` becomes `button.enabled:hover`.

Comment: Add value to the `disabled` attribute, it's ought if you want your code be valid with standards.

Comment: @Hauleth no value is valid HTML5  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418114/should-i-use-html5-syntax

Answer (score 76, accepted):

pointer-events: none will disable all hover behavior. very usefull for disabled elements

```
 button[disabled] { 
      pointer-events: none;

    }
```

Comment: First class recommendation! Thanks!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! doesn't work on IE < 10 and OperaMini though

Comment: just what i was going to say.

Comment: Gold!  This should be the accepted answer for sure.

Comment: this makes disabled elements click-through which might not be what you want

Answer (score 22):

I don't think there is a way to truly *ignore* a set of styles.

You could, however, create a more specific style that overrides the `hover` styles.

```
button[disabled]:hover {
  /* turn off button hover styles */
}
```

Comment: I had intended whatever fix to be used on a large but fixed set of elements.  This is probably the most flexible way to approach this though it will add some additional maintenance.

Comment: True. It's unfortunate that something like `inherit` doesn't scale for these situations. Fortunately though, this is at least a pure CSS solution. As opposed to some of the other JS or HTML markup solutions provided.

Answer (score 8):

I've just been struggling with this problem and came up with a solution using the css3 not selector. It's not supported by the older IE browsers but you can use selectivizr.js (or another) to add the functionality

```
button {
  // styles for  non-disabled buttons
}

button:hover:not([disabled]) {
  // styles for hover on non-disabled
}

button[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

After reading the responses available I found none of them would be suitable for me. I kept thinking there must be a simple solution to this.  In the end I just chained the pseudo classes. This worked perfectly.

```
button:enabled:hover { font-weight: bold }
```

Example:

```css
.hov:hover { color: red }
.hov2:enabled:hover { color: green }
```

```html
<p>Without fix</p>
<button class="hov">Hover me</button>
<button class="hov" disabled>Hover me</button>
<p>With fix</p>
<button class="hov2">Hover me</button>
<button class="hov2" disabled>Hover me</button>
```

Noticed I'm using if enabled pseudo code (:) and the hover pseudo code (:) code to perform the css.

I appreciated it's some time since this thread was opened, but thought it might help others.

Comment: Great ... and supports all modern browsers and IE 9+

Answer (score 2):

Make the hover style the same as the default. Use a class name to turn this feature on or off.

```
<button class="disabled" disabled>Click me</button>

button.disabled:hover { font-weight: inherit}
```

Comment: Note this would also affect *enabled* button styles. Which I don't believe is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this (but not as efficient as using `pointer-events: none;` ), is to set the same properties on both "disabled" and "hover when disabled":

```css
input:hover{
    color: #0CB;
}

input[type=button]:hover:disabled{
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Try Me !" />
<input type="button" value="Why not Me ?" disabled/>
```

It's not the most beautiful, but it works too.

Answer (score -1):

Put the property 'transform: none' in your overridden button class.

Comment: What difference would this make, given that the initial value of transform is none anyway?